# REVELATION 16:16

Tags: revelation, apocalyptic

Whats does MEGIDO mean in REVELATION 16:16?

Revelation 16:16 Christian Standard Bible (CSB)
16 So they assembled the kings at the place called in Hebrew, **Armageddon**. [a]

Footnotes:

> **16:16 Some  mss read Armagedon; Harmegedon; Mageddon; Magedon**